# How do I insert a graph of my signal readings / XCP readings during a test to my report using CAPL?

Tags: data-visualization, capl, canoe

I'm trying to add a graph in the report which represents how an XCP changes as i change the signal. I'm able to output this as teststeppass in the report as text. How do i use a graphical representation?

I'm using CANOE to automate some tests and need to try to add graphs.

I expect a graph on my report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a graphics window to your measurement setup. In the graphics window you configure your signals and XCP readings the way you want.

During testing, you can use the CAPL call `TestReportAddWindowCapture(...)` to generate a screenshot of this window and add it to your report.

Comment: Is there any way i can add or remove signals on the go? My main test has a lot of test cases inside it which deal different signals. Do i have to pre-configure a graphic window for each test case ?
I'm dealing with over a hundred Sysvars , XCPs and Signals.

Comment: I am not aware of any automation API to configure the graphics window, sorry.